# Filtering and comparing data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Reference: https://gyazo.com/b0e2b673c5ef57d6c2609142c6916546]

So what I want to do is remove the first word of every name in these columns. Example: "CMSgt Cin" needs to say "Cin" on my datasheet1. I have attempted to do that but am I getting errors.

[image: https://gyazo.com/8bc43b7eff8e487dc8fc99e9595f6ec6]

[image: https://gyazo.com/fc47e50d9d31bd844888fc7287816a9c]

After I have converted the names, I want the cells that do not apply to the conversion to remain blank on my datasheet1. So basically if the filter is looking for a name such as "CMSgt Cin" but only finds "--" in that cell, I want the filter just make the cell blank on my datasheet1.

My main goal is to see if the names on my reference sheet are also on another sheet which they should be on. So I am filtering and comparing two lists of data, and I want to make it so if they are on my reference sheet but notice sheet I'm comparing it to, their name should appear red. I am willing to talk on discord if this is too confusing to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so what I want to do is remove the first word of every name in these columns

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " ", 0, 1), 1, 2)
```

---

> I want the cells that do not apply to the conversion to remain blank on my datasheet1

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ", A1)), INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " ", 0, 1), 1, 2), )
```

---

> goal is to see if the names on my reference sheet are also on another sheet which they should be on

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 'another sheet'!A1:A, 1, 0))
```

---

> if they are on my reference sheet but notice sheet I'm comparing it to, their name should appear red

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A1, INDIRECT("'another sheet'!$A:$A"), INDIRECT("'another sheet'!$A1"))>1
```

---

> show all the people who are on my reference sheet but not my data sheet

```
=QUERY(FILTER({E:E;F:F;G:G;H:H;I:I;J:J}, 
   ISNA(MATCH({E:E;F:F;G:G;H:H;I:I;J:J}, Sheet3!A:A, 0))),
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null and Col1 <>'720th STG Flights'")
```

Comment: In my A column, I want it to show all the people who are on my reference sheet but not my data sheet, how would I apply that list bit of code to the A column, I am a bit confused. https://gyazo.com/c38f5b1538a54a6be0502cb88a62b039

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TckU2QTKoLYtaJkQioeOFK4X0OZ2P632lsiD4lon5ck/edit?usp=sharing